# Showing initially full image with PhotoView in Android

Tags: android, zooming, android-imageview, android-photoview

I am developing an Android app. In my application, I need zoom image features like in Facebook. So, I used this library - https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView. But I am having problem with showing full image when the image is first loaded.

This is how I set PhotoViewAttacher to ImageView

```
    photoViewAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);
    photoViewAttacher.setZoomable(true);
    photoViewAttacher.update();
```

This is the xml layout of imageview

```
      <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/item_details_image"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

What I am trying to do is I want the image to show fit to the screen if the image is bigger then screen size. No matter how big it is. But image can be smaller than screen size. I just want to show full image at initial. But the above code gives me this result.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, it cannot show the whole image. It showing only partially. If I want to see other area of image, I want to scroll or swipe because the image does not fit to screen initially. So that I tried to change the XML to show the whole area of image initially. This is the XML I changed to.

```
<ImageView

        android:id="@+id/item_details_image"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

As you can see I changed the height from match_parent to wrap_content. Scale type as well. When I changed to that, it shows the full image initially like this.

[image]

It shows full image but smaller. It is totally ok for me. That is what I want to have. The problem is with zoom feature. When I zoom up, the image cannot go bigger than the image height. See the screenshot below.

[image]

As you can see above, it is not showing full image when I zoom up. ImageView height is not changing.

Comment: I have got the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Use PhotoView instead of ImageView in xml.

Answer (score 3):

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_details_image"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

You Need to **match_parent** both **height or width**